# Execute Ssrs report from controller

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have some code that calls a report, but even if I pass parameters into the report the user still  needs to click the "View Report" button before the report itself will render.  Is there any way to change this?

```
Function Report(vm As ReportParameterViewModel) As ActionResult
    ''lazy loading of report details, path
    Dim reportDetails = Reports.Value
    reportDetails.Load(vm.ReportId)

    ''private function that returns ReportViewer and sets a few details of it
    Dim viewer = SetUpReportViewer()
    viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = reportDetails.ReportServerUrl
    viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportDetails.ReportPath
    viewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(GetParams(vm))
    viewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
    ViewBag.ReportViewer = viewer

    Return View()
End Function
```

Is there something I can add to have the report run immediately, without user interaction?

Comment: are you sure that all parameters are set to report parameters? above method is correct you can achieve by doing same.

Comment: @curiousguy the parameters are populating correctly through the `GetParams()` method.  The inputs on the report are filled out with the correct params passed in, but there is a "View Report" button that still needs to be clicked in order to generate the report.  Is this the expected functionality?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I've never tried from controller. I'm using simple function to call report. still have you tried to set `ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;` also I've provided my code here in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247645/the-request-failed-with-http-status-401-unauthorized-in-ssrs/33520764#33520764) - please have a look.

Comment: @curiousguy yeah, I mean this is basically what I am doing.  I am using app pool for authentication as opposed to creating ServerCredentials.  Inside the `SetUpReportViewer()` method it sets the width/height as well as the processing mode to remote.  Currently my hacky work-around is to find the "View Report" button and call `click` on it via js

Comment: also you need to check that report's all parameters should be hidden from report manager. it will surely work

Comment: Yes thank you.  I have solved everything except having the report execute on load, but we have determined that the database owner will have to make some changes to move forward