# "Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later" But I'm using 2016

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

- I have 2 Reporting Services servers, one is Reporting Services 2012 and the other 2016.
- There are reports and folders on both servers.
- I am using **Microsoft Report Viewer (WinForms dll) 10.0.0.0** in a **WPF** page
  wrapped on a **winforms** component to connect in **Remote mode** to my report server.
- I am **NOT** using 2005 reporting services or reports anywhere and have
  recompiled the reports in my report writer.

When I try to view a report in my WPF page I just get this message:

"*Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later*"

How can I stop this message and see my report appear?

Thanks in advance.
**Dave K.**

**Additional....**

I did a break point just after the reportviewer.RefreshReport() and dug deep and found this exception which shows ReportingServices2005 (but why??)...

*at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.**ReportingServices2005**.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SoapVersionMismatchException.ThrowIfVersionMismatch(SoapException e, String expectedEndpoint, String message, Boolean includeInnerException)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ServerReportSoapProxy.OnSoapException(SoapException e)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SoapReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String report, String historyId)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.get_AutoRefreshInterval()*

Comment: Verify that the RDLC is not referencing anything like `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005`.

Comment: Not 2005, the neaerest thing that I can see is...
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">

Comment: Or for the 2016 reports...
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/...
xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/...

Comment: I am using this in the view...  

    <Grid Background="White">  
        <WindowsFormsHost>  
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/>  
        </WindowsFormsHost>  
    </Grid>

Answer (score 0):

Found what it was.  I was using the report browser service "ReportService2010.asmx" in the url when 'Viewing' the reports.  Of course this is only used when getting a list of reports etc. from the repository.

I also now use the CustomSSRSCredentials class from [The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized IN SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247645/the-request-failed-with-http-status-401-unauthorized-in-ssrs) which is very good.

Now all working.